# Anki won't start. When clicked on the icon it starts to show up on the dock but after a while it disappears and nothing happens

Tags: software-installation

The installation was done from command line `sudo apt get-install anki` and when tried to run through command line by just typing `anki`, it showed the following

```
Qt warning: QApplication: invalid style override 'adwaita' passed, ignoring it.
Available styles: Windows, Fusion 
mpv too old for key rebinding
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/usr/local/share/anki/bin/PyQt5/Qt/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

PS. Running Elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera btw.

Answer (score 0):

I get trought of snap. Follow this link:
https://snapcraft.io/install/anki-woodrow/elementary